# Babel doesn't convert fetch api code

Tags: javascript, html, es6-promise, fetch-api

The fetch api is really helpful but unfortunately it doesn't work for most browsers especially internet explorer. I tried to convert my code from es6 to es5 using babel but it doesn't solve this issue. It still includes fetch when it is converted to es5. How can I get around this issue.
Here is the es6 code:

```
var btnText = document.getElementById('btnText');
var btnJson = document.getElementById('btnJson');
btnText.addEventListener("click",fetchBtnText);
function fetchBtnText() {
  fetch("sample.txt")
    .then((response) => response.text())
.then((data) => console.log(data))
}
```

Here is the conversion to es5

```
'use strict';
var btnText = document.getElementById('btnText');
var btnJson = document.getElementById('btnJson');
btnText.addEventListener("click", fetchBtnText);
function fetchBtnText() {
  fetch("sample.txt").then(function (response) {
    return response.text();
  }).then(function (data) {
    return console.log(data);
  });
}
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You could use a polyfill, like this
https://github.com/github/fetch

Comment: Can you explain why it doesn't convert that.

Comment: @StukedCoder Babel is `mainly used to convert ECMAScript 2015+ code into a backwards compatible version of JavaScript in current and older browsers or environments` as stated on their [home page](https://babeljs.io/docs/en/) and the Fetch API is not part of the ECMAScript/javascript language specification, but part of the Web APIs. See [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44058726/is-the-fetch-api-an-ecmascript-feature) for more details.